# In my C code i run into some trouble writing text when a signal gets triggered

Tags: c, linux, process, signals

My code builds a child process and multiple grandchildren (based on N_GRANDKIDDIES).
My problem appears in the handler for the SIGCHLD signal... When I write the pid of the current grandchild and another value, the outcome in the console is very inconsistent... there are often multiple rows missing, for example, like this:

```
PID:12311
PID:12312
PID:12314
PID:12313
File for Saving Signals
Grandchild with pid:12511 has called SIGUSR1 25139 times
(Missing the other grandchildren here)
Process returned 0 (0x0).....
```

Hope someone can help me here!

my Code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

#define TESTTIME 3
#define FNAME "testfile.txt"
#define N_GRANDKIDDIES 4
#define SLEEPSEC 0
#define SLEEPNSEC 2

// prototypen
int kiddyscode(void);
int grandkiddyscode();
int nanosleep(const struct timespec *req, struct timespec *rem);
void syserr(char* message);

// global
int pids[N_GRANDKIDDIES];
int counter[N_GRANDKIDDIES];
int n_grandkiddies;
int stop = 0;

void syserr(char* message)
{
   int i,j;
   j=strlen(message);
   printf("Erro ");

   for(i=0;i<j;i++)
   {
       printf("%c",*message++);
   }
   printf("Error No.: %d\n",errno);

   strerror(errno);
   exit(0);
   }

void initSignalhandler(int sig, struct sigaction sa , void (*handler))
{
   memset (&sa, 0,sizeof(sa));

   if(sig == SIGCHLD || sig == SIGUSR1) sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;

   sa.sa_handler = handler;
   sigaction(sig, &sa, NULL);

   if ((int)(uintptr_t)sigaction == -1)
   {
       syserr("Error SigAction\n");
       exit(-1);
   }
}

void handle_sigalrm(int sig)
{
   stop = 1;
}


void handle_sigusr(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *data)
{
   for (int i=0; i<N_GRANDKIDDIES-1; i++)
   {
       if ((int)si->si_pid == pids[i]) counter[i]++;
   }
}

void handle_sigchld(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *data)
{
   pid_t pid;
   int status, i;

   FILE *fp;
   fp = fopen(FNAME, "a");

    // Fehler
   if (fp == NULL)
   {
       syserr("Error\n");
       exit(-1);
   }

   wait(NULL);
   n_grandkiddies--;

   for (i=0; i<N_GRANDKIDDIES-1;i++)
   {
       pid = waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG);
       if (pid > 0)
       {
           n_grandkiddies--;
           fprintf(fp, "Grandchild with pid:%i has callled SIGUSR1 %i times\n", pids[i], counter[i]);

       }
   }

   fclose(fp);
}

int main()
{
   FILE *fp;
   fp = fopen(FNAME, "w");

   if (fp == NULL)
   {
       syserr("Error\n");
       exit(-1);
   }

   fprintf(fp ,"File for Saving Signals\n");
   fclose(fp);

   switch(fork())
   {
       case -1:
           syserr("Fork Error\n");
           exit(-1);
           break;
       case 0:
           kiddyscode();
           return 0;
       default:
           if(wait(NULL) == -1)
           {
               syserr("Error");
           }
   }

   fp = fopen(FNAME, "r");

   if (fp == NULL)
   {
       syserr("Error\n");
       exit(-1);
   }

   char c;
   while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
       printf("%c", c);
   fclose(fp);

   return 0;
}

int kiddyscode(void)
{
   struct sigaction sa1;
   initSignalhandler(SIGCHLD, sa1, handle_sigchld);
   initSignalhandler(SIGUSR1, sa1, handle_sigusr);


   for(int i = 0; i < N_GRANDKIDDIES; i++)
   {
       pids[i]= fork();

       // Erstellung durch fork
       // -1 = Fehler
       if(pids[i] == -1)
       {
           syserr("Fork Error\n");
           exit(-1);
       }
       else if(pids[i]==0)
       {
           grandkiddyscode();
           exit(0);
       }
       // wird von Kiddy ausgeführt
       else
       {
           n_grandkiddies++;
       }
   }

   int i=0;
   while (n_grandkiddies>0){
       i++;
       pause();
       if (errno==EINTR) continue;
       if (i>1) break;
       continue;
   }

   return 0;
}

int grandkiddyscode()
{
   printf("PID:%i\n", getpid());
   // Signalhandler initialisieren
   struct sigaction sa1;
   initSignalhandler(SIGALRM, sa1, handle_sigalrm);

   // Alarm stellen
   alarm(TESTTIME);

   int ppid = getppid();

   struct timespec ts;
   ts.tv_sec = SLEEPSEC;
   ts.tv_nsec = SLEEPNSEC;

   while (stop != 1)
   {
       kill(ppid, SIGUSR1);
       nanosleep(&ts, NULL);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aside: see [`signal-safety(7)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) for a list of POSIX specified functions that are safe to call from within the context of a signal handler. Hint: `printf` is not listed.

Comment: Don't declare `nanosleep()` in your code — use the correct header: `#include <time.h>`.

Comment: Also, the line `strerror(errno);` does nothing useful — you would have to print the value returned.

Comment: `char c; while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)` if `char` is unsigned, then EOF, a negative value (usually -1), will never be found by this comparison. Use `int c;`.

Comment: The grandchildren sleep for 2 nanoseconds after signalling the child process — that's essentially no time at all.  Consequently, you are sending signals far faster than the receiving process can respond, and the extra signals are not queued (they are not real-time signals), and the extra ones are lost.  Try using `#define SLEEPNSEC 2000000` (2 milliseconds); you should see a different result.  You also have lots of verboten activity in your signal handler — file stream I/O is not allowed (though file descriptor I/O is).

Comment: Thanks alot! Soif I understand correctly it is "normal" that I dont get everything printed out because fprintf() is not save to use in signalhandlers?

Comment: None of `fopen`, `fprintf`, or `fclose` are safe to use in a signal handler (check the list of functions marked *async-signal-safe* in [`signal-safety(7)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html)). The results you see are not "normal", they are one of many unpredictable outcomes from running code with no guarantees of safety. To Jonathan's second point, see also the section in [`signal(7)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) labeled *"Queueing and delivery semantics for standard signals"* - *"Standard signals do not queue."* is the general take-away.

Comment: Signals were originally intended to signal exceptional conditions.  They were *not* intended as a general-purpose interprocess communication (IPC) mechanism.  If you send lots of signals in quick succession, you will generally lose some of them.

Comment: And then there's SIGCHLD. Everything I just said about signals is doubly true of SIGCHLD.  There *might* be a C/Unix guru somewhere in the world who is able to catch SIGCHLD reliably, without succumbing to ruinously cascading race conditions, but if so, I've never met that person.  My own rule is: *never* try to use SIGCHLD; it's impossible to use correctly; just pretend it doesn't exist.  (Sorry for the cargo-cult advice, but I stand by it.)

Comment: Well thanks for this summary. I am kinda confused now why I learn wrong things or bad practices in university :D But thanks anyways you guys helped me a lot

Comment: Additionally, `stop` should technically be of type [`sig_atomic_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/sig_atomic_t).